# Which recent Parity release can be used to synch a node for use with Mist 0.8.8

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, parity, fast-sync

I am finding Geth exceptionally slow to synch.  I found Parity to be much faster. However recent Parity releases make it very complex just to use the Parity client to synchronise and then open Mist.  It would also be helpful to know how to use just the Parity node client and then how to set the dir path to point to the correct chaindata folder rather than create a new one and synch from genesis again.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Any version should work. Run `parity --geth` [before launching Mist Browser](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Using-Parity-with-Mist) or use the [Parity Browser](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Parity-Wallet).